# Cursor jumps in the beginning of the input line after each letter in 1 millisecond in browsers on some sites (e.g.Youtube comments field)

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, browser

AS I typing a letter in the field in 1 millisecond cursor jumps in the beginning of the line of typing field so that text is typed invert-(I only can send some message on particular sites(you tube comments and https://translate.yandex.com/ for example after typing it in notebook, copying and pasting in youtube comments). I try to understand it hard and up to this moment I've learnt that it relates to CSS and particular line appears while it stops (). Please help me to understand on my low level of knowledge how can I stop this problem. Where I can reset settings on my win 10 system to stop my two browsers to act this way. (It started to occur after I deleted cookies of a couple of sites and win defender says no viruses..).

I tried to learn how to implement (or encode) a script that some people put forth on some sites into in-built system but I failed up to this moment and it disturbes me. 1) what code or script 2)where or how to paste it or type in as I imagine it should be to solve the issue. I've learnt how to read scripts in browsers (shift+ctrl+I) and they call it css in js and I compared to pages where issue stop to occur when I deleted some lines with div(many tries and I understood by comparing) and reloaded and the problem disappeared when div was set typing settings to default(). Sorry for being so prolix as I'm from the opposite hemisphere, lerned English and not quite sure wheather to be understood. As this drilling my mind I can't do anything but finding solution. Thank you, hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you only use Chromium-based browsers, then you should see if the problem also occurs in a Gecko-based browser. If the error only occurs in Chromium based browsers, then it must be a Chromium bug. Otherwise it can only be the system.

Chromium based browsers are e.g.:

- Google Chrome
- Opera
- Edge
- brave

Gecko based browsers are e.g.:

- Firefox
- Goal

You can find more information on how to report a bug in the Google Chrome Help Center [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop).

Comment: Thank you! But could you explain please-how to fix  a Chromium bug?

Answer (score 0):

So, I have just managed this problem cause my mind coldn't set still.. I noticed that when I used the Linguist translator extension that was installed on both of my browsers Edge and Chrome for translation of from native language it just couldn't stop translating changing letters and the pattern was some bold letters in the beginning of sentences which also occured in typing on site input fields and youtube auto-generated subtitles. I removed extensions and the problem ceased to manifest itself.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).